# пробный Яндекс.Контест, задание на графы. Код не проходит один из тестов по времени (time-limit-exceeded). Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, графы

Условие задачи:

Не секрет, что некоторые программисты очень любят путешествовать. Хорошо всем известный программист Петя тоже очень любит путешествовать, посещать музеи и осматривать достопримечательности других городов.
Для перемещений между из города в город он предпочитает использовать машину. При этом он заправляется только на станциях в городах, но не на станциях по пути. Поэтому он очень аккуратно выбирает маршруты, чтобы машина не заглохла в дороге. А ещё Петя очень важный член команды, поэтому он не может себе позволить путешествовать слишком долго. Он решил написать программу, которая поможет ему с выбором очередного путешествия. Но так как сейчас у него слишком много других задач, он попросил вас помочь ему.
Расстояние между двумя городами считается как сумма модулей разности по каждой из координат. Дороги есть между всеми парами городов.

Формат ввода
В первой строке входных данных записано количество городов
n
(
2
≤
n
≤
1
0
0
0
). В следующих
n
строках даны два целых числа: координаты каждого города, не превосходящие по модулю миллиарда. Все города пронумерованы числами от 1 до
n
в порядке записи во входных данных.
В следующей строке записано целое положительное число
k
, не превосходящее двух миллиардов, — максимальное расстояние между городами, которое Петя может преодолеть без дозаправки машины.
В последней строке записаны два различных числа — номер города, откуда едет Петя, и номер города, куда он едет.

Формат вывода
Если существуют пути, удовлетворяющие описанным выше условиям, то выведите минимальное количество дорог, которое нужно проехать, чтобы попасть из начальной точки маршрута в конечную. Если пути не существует, выведите -1.

Код:

```
import sys

n = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip()).    # вывод количества городов

city_koord = dict()           #словарь номер города - координаты
mygraph = dict()  # словарь номер города - список городов, до которых 
                                                             можно доехать
count = 0

for i in range(n):
    koord = sys.stdin.readline().strip()     # вывод координат городов
    koord = koord.split(' ')
    koord = list(koord)
    koord = list(map(int, koord))
    city_koord[i + 1] = koord            
    mygraph[i + 1] = []

k = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())     # вывод максимального расстояния

st_end_city = sys.stdin.readline().strip()  # вывод городов начала и конца
st_end_city = st_end_city.split(' ')

st_end_city = list(st_end_city)
st_end_city = list(map(int, st_end_city))

 #ниже функция для создания графа городов, между которыми можно 
 #       передвигаться.  например {1 : [2, 4]}, 2:[3, 5]

def takegraph(citydict, v):
    city1 = citydict[v]
    for key in range(1, len(citydict) + 1):
        city2 = citydict[key]
        x = abs(city1[0] - city2[0])
        y = abs(city1[1] - city2[1])
        if x + y <= k:
            mygraph[v].append(key)
    if v < len(citydict):
        takegraph(citydict, v + 1)

takegraph(city_koord, 1)

def dograph(gggraph, start_graph, end_graph):
    stack = [(start_graph, [start_graph])] 
    while stack:
        (vertex, path) = stack.pop()
        for next in set(gggraph[vertex]) - set(path):
            if next == end_graph:
                yield path + [next]
            else:
                stack.append((next, path + [next]))

a = list(dograph(mygraph, st_end_city[0], st_end_city[1]))

a.sort(key = len)

if len(a) != 0:
    count = len(a[0]) - 1



print(-1 if count == 0 else count)
```

Comment: На первый взгляд в коде ошибка "city1 = citydict[v]" - берёте элемент справочника и ниже выполняете строку "y = abs(city1[1] - city2[1])". У вас в переменной только один элемент тот что вы положили туда выше по коду а значит вы можете вызвать только city1[0]. В результате получите "list index out of range".  Что касается скорости выполнения есть базовые принципы, внимательно с рекурсией, старайтесь не вызывать функции внутри циклов это довольно затратно, не злоупотребляйте IF внутри циклов.

Answer (score 1):

После построения графа вам стоит использовать алгоритм поиска в ширину (BFS). Он позволяет за O(E), где Е - количество рёбер в графе, проверить достижимость вершины u из v, а также посчитать минимальное количество рёбер, необходимое для этого - как раз то, что нам надо.
Прилагаю пример реализации bfs на питоне (в целях оптимизации рекомендую реализовывать очередь в виде связного списка (например, queue.Queue в python), вместо list в примере):

```
def bfs(s, adj):
    # Тут храним стоимость прохода до вершины
    cost = [-1] * len(adj)
    # 'Стоимость' пути s -> s = 0
    cost[s] = 0
    queue = [s]
    while queue:
        v = queue.pop(0)
        # запускаем обход из вершины v
        for w in adj[v]: 
            # проверка на посещенность
            if cost[w] == -1: 
                # добавление вершины в очередь
                queue.append(w) 
                # подсчитываем стоимость пути до вершины
                cost[w] = cost[v] + 1 
    

adj = [    
#список смежности
    [1,3], # 0
    [0,3,4,5], # 1
    [4,5], # 2
    [0,1,5], # 3
    [1,2], # 4
    [1,2,3] # 5
]

cost = bfs(0, adj)
# Выведем 'стоимость' пути из вершины 0 в 2
# Если cost[u] = -1, значит, вершина u недостижима из стартовой вершины
print(cost[2])
```

Comment: граф взвешенный, поиск в ширину работает с невзвешенными графами

Answer (score 1):

Такое решение проходит их тест:

```
import sys

def bfs(s, adj):
    # Тут храним стоимость прохода до вершины
    cost = [-1] * len(adj)
    #print('cost =', cost)
    # Стоимость пути s -> s = 0
    cost[s] = 0
    #print('cost =', cost)
    queue = [s]
    #print('queue =', queue)
    while queue:
        v = queue.pop(0)
        # запускаем обход из вершины v
        for key, value in adj[v].items():
            # проверка на посещенность
            if cost[key] == -1:
                # добавление вершины в очередь
                queue.append(key)
                #print('queue =', queue)
                # подсчитываем стоимость пути до вершины
                cost[key] = cost[v] + value
                #print('cost =', cost)
    return cost

try:
    n = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
    city_coords = list(list())
    for _ in range(n):
        city_coords.append(list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split())))
    k = int(sys.stdin.readline().strip())
    city_from, city_to = list(map(int, sys.stdin.readline().strip().split()))
    adj = dict(dict())
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i):
            dist = abs(city_coords[i][0] - city_coords[j][0]) + abs(city_coords[i][1] - city_coords[j][1])
            if dist <= k:
                if i in adj:
                    adj[i][j] = 1#dist
                else:
                    adj[i] = {j: 1}#dist
                if j in adj:
                    adj[j][i] = 1#dist
                else:
                    adj[j] = {i: 1}#dist
    # Выведем 'стоимость' пути из вершины city_from в city_to
    # Если cost[u] = -1, значит, вершина u недостижима из стартовой вершины
    if city_from - 1 in adj and city_to - 1 in adj:
        cost = bfs(city_from - 1, adj)
        print(cost[city_to - 1])
    else:
        print(-1)
except Exception as e:
    print(-1)
```

Comment: Это поиск в ширину?

Answer (score 0):

Дейкстра будет быстрее и потребует меньше памяти. (не нужно строить граф). решение на С++ :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>
#include <algorithm>

static const int maxRoute = 1001;

struct city
{
     long x {};
     long y {};
     int index { -1 };
     int distance { maxRoute };
     int distFrom { -1 };
};

int main()
{
     int size {};
     long power {};
     int depart {}, destin {};
     std::string inputBuff;
     std::cin >> inputBuff;

     std::vector< city > array;

     //ввод данных
     try
     {
          size = std::stoi( inputBuff );
          if( !size )
               return 0;
          array.resize( size );

          for( int i = 0; i < size; ++i )
          {
               city p;
               std::cin >> inputBuff;
               p.x = std::stol( inputBuff );
               std::cin >> inputBuff;
               p.y = std::stol( inputBuff );
               p.index = i;
               array[ i ] = p;
          }

          std::cin >> inputBuff;
          power = std::stol( inputBuff );

          std::cin >> inputBuff;
          depart = std::stoi( inputBuff ) - 1;
          array[ depart ].distance = 0;
          array[ depart ].distFrom = array[ depart ].index;

          std::cin >> inputBuff;
          destin = std::stoi( inputBuff ) - 1;
     }
     catch( std::invalid_argument const& ex )
     {
          std::cout << "std::invalid_argument::what(): " << ex.what() << '\n';
     }

     //решение
     auto cityGreater = []( const city& l, const city& r ) { return l.distance > r.distance; };

     std::make_heap( array.begin(), array.end(), cityGreater );
     city curPoint;

     while( 1 )
     {
          curPoint = array.front();
          if( curPoint.index == destin )
               break;

          for( auto it = array.begin() + 1; it != array.end(); ++it )
          {
//               double calcDist = sqrt( std::pow( curPoint.x - it->x, 2 ) + std::pow( curPoint.y - it->y, 2 ) );
               long   calcDist = std::abs( curPoint.x - it->x ) + std::abs( curPoint.y - it->y );
               if( calcDist > power )
                    continue;
               if( ( curPoint.distance + 1 ) < it->distance )
               {
                    it->distance = curPoint.distance + 1;
                    it->distFrom = curPoint.index;
               }
          }

          std::pop_heap( array.begin(), array.end(), cityGreater );
          array.pop_back();
          if( !std::is_heap( array.begin(), array.end(), cityGreater ) )
               std::make_heap( array.begin(), array.end(), cityGreater );
     }

     if( curPoint.distFrom != -1 )
          std::cout << curPoint.distance << std::endl;
     else
          std::cout << -1 << std::endl;

     return 0;
}
```